# .net c# Basler Pylon ip camera

Tags: .net, wpf, camera, ip, basler

I am trying to build the standard interface as following in the pylon basler website
I got a Basler BIP2 1300c - dn, type of camera its an ip camera.
I use as the following in the trailer, but .net doesn't recognize or find any of my camera's .
My camera is PoE connected over LAN , maybe that's the problem?
In "the trailer" (??) there is only option (??) , connect the camera with USB3.0
But my camera does not have USB3, its a POE LAN camera.
Is there anyway I can use the Pylon .net windows control with my camera type?